# How to compare elements in 2 different string arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to write a program that inputs a string and then outputs the length of the longest substring that does not have any repeated characters.

For example: input: abcacbcc
output: 3.

However, when I try to compare an element in my substring with an element in my input string, the compiler does not allow me to compare with an error message:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2677   binary '==': no global operator found which takes type
> 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  line: 22"

How am I able to fix this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    string substr[100];
    int static max = 0;
    int static count = 0;
    int static index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < str.size()); i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[i + 1]) {
            substr[index] = str[i];
            index++;
            count++;
            if (count >= max) {
                max = count;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
                if (str[i+1] == substr[j]) { //**problem here**
                    count = 0;
                    substr[0] = "\0";
                    index = 0;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
            count = 0;
            substr[0] = "\0";
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: str[i+1] is a character. str is a std::string. You can't compare a character to a string directly. The compiler protects you from typos. If you really want to compare characters, you might write (str[i+1] == substr[j][0]) e.g. to compare the first character.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare `str[i+1]`, which is a `char`, with `substr[j]`, which is an `std::string`. This results in an error as there is no operator `==` comparing a `char` with a `std::string`.

Judging by the problem statement and how you've written the program, I'm guessing you're using `substr` to store the current substring. Instead of declaring it as an array of `std::string`, for your purposes I think what you want is an array of `char`.

So, you could delcare `substr` like `char substr[100]`, then change:

```
substr[0] = "\0";
```

to

```
substr[0] = '\0';
```